# Prism - The subscribed event doesn't trigger

Tags: wpf, prism, autofac

I have the following situation (I'm working on a WPF application but I don't think that's important):

- Class A;
- Class B that it is invoked from A;

A constructor:

```
public A(IEventAggregator eventAggregator){
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

    Button = new DelegateCommand(f);

    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Subscribe(handleMyEvent);
}
```

And at the bottom:

```
 private void f()
 {
        //here I create a new instance of B with Autofac
        var bootstrap = new Bootstrapper();
        var container = bootstrap.BootStrap();
        BInstance= container.Resolve<B>(new NamedParameter("id", "myId"),
            new NamedParameter("action", "my_action"));
        BInstance.Show(); //here in real I create a view that has a DataContext = B instance
    }
```

Also, B constructor looks like this:

```
    public B(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        // some other stuff
    }
```

In the B class at some point I want to trigger the event 'MyEvent' that I have subscribed in the A constructor. So, I do something like this:

```
    private void f()
    {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish();
    }
```

My problem is, simply, that the event doesn't trigger (the function handleMyEvent never perform its work).

Important thing: 
if I replace this line in the f function (on A):

```
BInstance= container.Resolve<B>(new NamedParameter("id", "myId"),
        new NamedParameter("action", "my_action"));
```

With:

```
BInstace = createB() // where createB is a Func<B>
```

it works without any problem. I really don't get why this is happening. 
The main problem is that I must pass some parameters to the B ctor (that's not totally true, since I pass these parameters to another class that instantiate B but doesn't matter).

Note: I'm working with Autofac as dependencies injector and Prism for the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` and `B` in your setup work on different event aggregators. Of course, one doesn't know of the subscriptions of the other.

You have to create both `A` and `B` from the same container:

```
private void f()
{
    BInstance = _container.Resolve<B>(new NamedParameter("id", "myId"),
        new NamedParameter("action", "my_action"));
    BInstance.Show(); //here in real I create a view that has a DataContext = B instance
}
```

For this to work, `A` needs the container:

```
public A(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IContainer container){
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    _container = container;
}
```

But beware, injecting the container is a code smell, to say the least. If this a real app, create a factory class to produce your `B` instances.

Comment: I don't think that it's the case because in my Autofac builder I have this: builder.RegisterType<EventAggregator>().As<IEventAggregator>().SingleInstance(); and anyway this does not explain why if I use a Func all work...

Comment: You could add the code of your `Bootstrapper`... I can only guess what's happening inside `BootStrap()`

Comment: I accept this answer because I think that it pointed out what the problem is. I suppose that the event is not triggered because the eventAggregator objects are not the same on these classes. Not sure how the ".SingleInstance()" works (is it a single instance for container, maybe?). So, it provided a good hint to bypass the setback.

Comment: I haven't that much experience with autofac, but I would be surprised if _any_ container treats lifetime in a way other than that. If else, what would you expect to happen if you registered a type as `.SingleInstance()` on one container instance and transient on another container instance?